# PHP exploding line breaks with uploaded files

Tags: php

Data files that users submit on my site are formatted like this:

```
Text text text text text
text texttext text text
text text text text 

text text text text text 
text text text text 
text text text
```

While developing my php script to read these files, I would explode() the file after using `file_get_contents` with the delimiter `\n\n` which would make an array from the above example.

But now that I am transitioning to a live site, and am developing the form to submit the file, this explode technique no longer works.

```
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $file) {
   $fname = file_get_contents($file);
   $rows = explode("\n\n", $fname);
   //do work
}
```

When I `echo $row[0]` the entire uploaded file is returned, instead of just the first paragraph. $rows[1] is empty. **Why isn't explode working here?**

Comment: Are you sure your line feed is not CRLF `\r\n`? Is this a windows file? A Mac file? A nix file?

Comment: @Michael OP wants to separate only the two blocks of 'text' in two parts of the array

Comment: Look at the file with a hex editor and you will immediately know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to normalize line endings:

```
$c = file_get_contents($file);
$c = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r"), array("\n", "\n"), $c);
$rows = explode("\n\n", $c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to difference in new line character between your local dev machine and on live machine. use correct new line on target machine.